# c# how do I convert my picture coords to grid coords in game

Tags: c#, coordinates

```
 private void PictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs me)
        {

            Image b = pictureBox1.Image;
             double x = b.Width * me.X / 200;
             double y = b.Height * me.Y / 200;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", x, y));
        }
```

I'm new to C# and have an image that is 589 width and 594px height.
Row on the picture is grids the grid size from top left to bottom right is 200.
My code doesn't show the correct value, maybe I am wrong? So, I don't want the image position, I only want the value from the Grid.

Hope you know what I mean and thanks for helping me.

Comment: _"it dont show the correct value"_ - read [ask] and explain what values you expect and what values you actually get. Also, the dimensions of the `PictureBox.Image` may be different from the dimensions of the `PictureBox` itself.

Comment: You want to keep the ration the same between X & Y.  So if you are going to scale you want to take the max of X or Y.  So you want either b.Width = 200 -10 (a margin) or b.Height = 200 - 10.

Comment: im not sure what i do wrong, i dont want the image position

Comment: Dear your question is not clear. What exactly you want? You want to read the image intensity according to the fitted image in grid or you want to match the grid x,y to original x,y of image. Please make it clear so that we can answer

Comment: i want to read the image intensity according to the fitted image in grid

i know that i have to calculate : my width: 589 / 200 is  2.97 my factor X
And 594/200 is 2.945 but now i need to * or / the values? of X and Y Axes. :)

Comment: Hey my friends i fixxed it myslef one Question: 
X say: 234,2394240 and Y: 23,4022022 
how can i do it that he show only he 234:23 

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("X={0}, Y={1}", x, y));

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good

`
Please verify if the PictureBox1 property SizeMode is set to StretchImage

`

Comment: I have set but its not the right value :(
here is preview of my Image https://prnt.sc/tpvihn

Comment: Did you set margin to 0 if not set all margin to 0 and try. Change denominator from 200 to 200f